# Getting Button values for images using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I have  Order and OrderDetails in my Page. For each OrderId i have table which display OrderDetails which is displayed in a table. In the OrderDetails I have to do paging.
I display the limit of Orderdetails to 5 records for each OrderId. I have to button "Previous" and "Next" Buttons. when i click "Next" i should show th Next 5 records for the particular OrderId.

Problem is the Button are styled to diplay as a image. Now when i click the button i need to pass the OrderId to the calling function. If i set the value for the Button then i see the previous or next button image along the value which is cluttered.

There are 2 for loop. first For loop to display the Order. Second For loop to diplay the OrderDetails for Each order. I need to get the corresponding OrderId on the button which is clicked If the Next Button is clicked for OrderId - 1 then i need to get the OrderId in the Next Event using Knockout js

Please let me know for any possible ways using knockout js

Order Id 1
    OrderDate   Amount
    10/12/2016  100
    10/12/2016  100

```
Previous(this is a image)   Next (this is a image)
```

Order Id 2
    OrderDate   Amount
    10/12/2016  100
    10/12/2016  100

```
Previous    Next



   <ul class="pager">
       <li>
         <span>
               <input type="button" class="btn dsg-back-btn" value="" title="Previous Page" data-bind="event: { click: $root.btnPrevPage }" />
         </span>
       </li>
      <li>
         <span>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm dsg-next-btn" value="" title="Next Page" data-bind="event: { click: $root.btnNextPage }" />
         </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you have your models structures but If orderId is a part of your orderDetail model then in your click function you will have an access to it no need to pass.

```
self.btnPrevPage  = function (item){
   // here you get item that is clicked. 
  console.log(item)
}
self.btnNextPage = function (item){
   // here you get item that is clicked
  console.log(item)
}
```

If it is not there then you can choose either one of the below solutions to pass a parameter

**Solution 1:** you can wrap your click function inside a JS function like:

```
data-bind="click: function(){ $root.btnPrevPage(yourOrderId)}"
data-bind="click: function(){ $root.btnPrevPage(yourOrderId)}"
```

**Solution 2** : you can use bind context.

```
data-bind="click: $root.btnNextPage.bind(yourOrderId)"
data-bind="click: $root.btnPrevPage.bind(yourOrderId)}"
```